# Generic type not recognised properly by Typescript

Tags: typescript

We have following TypeScript code:

```js
type Option = {
  name: string;
};

export const filterOptions = <T extends string>(
  options: Record<T, Option>,
): unknown[] =>
  Object.entries(options)
    .map(([key, entry]) => ({
      key,
      ...entry, // <--- Error: Spread types may only be created from object types.
    }))
    .filter(() => {
      // do filtering stuff...
    });
```

The expected type of `entry` is `Option`, but TS doesn't recognise this and assumes it is `unknown`. The issue seems to be the generic type `T`, because changing the type of `options` to `Record<string, Option>` changes the type of `entry` to `Option` (as expected).

Here is a [TS Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7KBeKBvAUFKKAhgLYQBcUAzsAE4IoDmA3DgL4s4QAeYSNwUAMapqUAGYIANsAg04iERigAeACpRuMlABNKVWvQYA%20ABR4oSeMhSUKAJQjCa2tQBpYV1Edc4AlBQBXFABrFCQAdxQAbQBdDCNzGAAjACtHYAA6CBQDCEoTSwUbX3N8DOJCMBMTKOCIEHds2hAY33ioE1x8bqg6htLujKGmmn6e1l8SnoyJaVlqtvQjbAH8AHo1qG0kcSkZOkZ9ALExIYyBiZYgA)

What are we getting wrong? Why is the type not recognised properly?

Comment: You need just provide `Object.entries` with explicit generic argument like here: https://tsplay.dev/mMVjzW . Let me know if it wirks for you

Comment: Thanks, this works :-) But it still feels a bit like a workaround... I don't understand why the type can be inferred without generics, but can't be inferred with generics ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: What is the purpose of your type parameter `T`? It only occurs in one parameter and not the return type, so your function would have essentially the same signature if you just deleted it and replaced it with `string`.

Comment: This is just a function stub to outline the issue, the generic type is part of the return type in the end and helps to have a better type safety in the code, which uses this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked the `Object.entries()` typing:

```
    /**
     * Returns an array of key/values of the enumerable properties of an object
     * @param o Object that contains the properties and methods. This can be an object that you created or an existing Document Object Model (DOM) object.
     */
    entries<T>(o: { [s: string]: T } | ArrayLike<T>): [string, T][];
```

### Option 1

It appears, you can pass the value argument type to `Object.entries()` explicitly. This way it regonizes the `typings`

```js
const filterOptions = <T extends string>(
  options: Record<T, Option>,
) => {

  return Object.entries<Option>(options) // added option type here!
  .map(([key, entry]) => ({
      key,
      ...entry, // It knows for sure now..
  }))
  .filter(() => {
      // do filtering stuff...
  });
}
```

#### Option 2

The `Record` typings make use of `symbols` / `numbers` and `strings` as keys.

```
/**
 * Construct a type with a set of properties K of type T
 */
 type Record<K extends keyof any, T> = {
  [P in K]: T;
};
```

For example, this does work:

```
const d = Symbol('somedescripton')

const a: Record<string, Option> = {
  'a': {name: 'strrst'},
  b: {name:'sdfsdf'},

  0: {name: 'srfsdfds'},
  d: {name: 'sdfsdfd'}
}
```

The `Object.entries()` will convert it to `string` keys but it accepts still, `Symbols` and `numbers` aswell!!^
So for having a `Record` type with only `string` keys you would have it to type yourself for being able to omit the explicit casting:

```
type StringRecord<T extends string, K> = {[key in keyof T]: K }

const filterOptions = <T extends string>(
  options: StringRecord<T, Option>,
) => {

  return Object.entries(options)
  .map(([key, entry]) => ({
      key,
      ...entry, // works now.. 
  }))
  .filter(() => {
      // do filtering stuff...
  });
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't help... sorry... The Generics are on purpose, just deleting the generics wouldn't make it any better

Comment: Updated my answer, just giving you my thoughts^^

Comment: The update is very helpful, Thank you. Will accept this